# Publicação de App na Apple Store com conteúdo restrito

Tags: ios, app, mac

Nós últimos dias, dei de frente com um problema na publicação de um App na Apple, ela simplesmente me bloqueia de eu querer que o usuário use usuário/senha para ter acesso a todo o conteúdo do App. Motivo: é um App educacional, e a escola fornece um id/senha para o aluno, ele é somente para o uso de instituições de ensino.

A Apple me exige que qualquer usuário tenha acesso a todo conteúdo sem precisar logar, porém vários aplicativos dentro da loja tem a mesma regra de negocio, e a Apple me bloqueia por este mesmo motivo e os demais Apps estão rodando normalmente.

Minha duvida é, será que esses publicadores burlaram de algum jeito essas exigências? Se foi como posso fazer, ou qual a melhor maneira de eu levar meu App com essa regra de negocio dentro da Loja.

Comment: Tive esse mesmo problema com uma atualização de um aplicativo (o mesmo já tinha sido publicado com conteúdo somente com usuário e senha), eles alegam que o aplicativo tem que exibir para o usuário um conteúdo prévio antes que ele forneça qualquer tipo de dado, aconselho a criar alguma área do app que tenha informações institucional ou criar um tutorial com imagens internas do app (pode ser uma solução, nunca tentei isso, mas vejo vários apps assim e conteúdo privado), ou criar um belo de um argumento para que eles aprovem (e tenha sorte kkk)

Comment: Jeferson Obrigado pela resposta,
O App tem a parte de experimentar, que contem 10% dos conteúdos, para que os professores possam testar sem ter um cadastro, mas mesmo assim ele rejeitaram, falaram que o app tem que ter todo conteúdo liberado caso o usuário não queria usar um login/senha, estou tenso com isso =/, tem escola que só usa Ipad =/

Comment: Estou enfrentando este problema, é algo insano pensar que eles testam todos aplicativos de forma manual. O pior é que estão demorando de 2 a 3 dias para uma resposta.

Comment: Você mandou na justificativa que o app exige login/senha previamente fornecido ou simplesmente submeteu? Pois já publiquei 2 apps, um deles sendo educacional e outro coorporativo e ambos foram aceitos sem problemas. A tela inicial de ambos é uma tela de login apenas, sem acesso a mais nada.

Comment: Luis Henrique, muito obrigado pela dica, ontem mesmo eu mandei o login/senha testes para eles, e vamos ver que vai dar agora =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se um aplicativo que é publicado na App Store exige algum login é necessário que você forneça uma conta de teste para que durante o período de revisão eles possam avaliar se o conteúdo e as funcionalidades do aplicativo estão de acordo com as diretrizes.

Os aplicativos que estão na App Store e possuem alguma forma de login, não foi burlado, provavelmente enviaram uma conta de teste.

Comment: O que acontece Gian, é que a Apple esta aplicando a regra de que o app exiba o conteúdo para o usuário antes de pedir qualquer cadastro.
Mesmo fornecendo o login na hora do envio eles avaliam isso agora, já tive problemas até por te pedido o gênero do indivíduo no cadastro, eles alegaram que tenho que da a opção do cara informar se ele quiser

Comment: Estranho, a pouco tempo atrás publiquei um app, não mostrava nada sem efetuar o login, e passou normalmente. Foi rejeitado na primeira vez pois eu havia esquecido de fornecer tais informações.

Comment: Gian eles estão me informando agora, que é necessario ter o conteudo aberto, pois o usuario não é obrigado jogar com um registro . é registro é uma opção a +.